# How to remove array index from a json_encode php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to remove numbers that is being display in my json 2d array. I first had an 2d array that is dynamic and deletes elements from that array. Then it converts the array to a json 2d array. The problem is I don't want the numbers at the start.

**Like below**

```
[ 

"1": {"StateName":"Alaska","StateAbbr":"AK"}, 
"2": {"StateName":"Alabama","StateAbbr":"AL"}, 
"3": {"StateName":"Arkansas","StateAbbr":"AR"}, 
"4": {"StateName":"Arizona","StateAbbr":"AZ"}, 
"5": {"StateName":"California","StateAbbr":"CA"}, 
"6": {"StateName":"Colorado","StateAbbr":"CO"}, 
"7": {"StateName":"Connecticut","StateAbbr":"CT"} 

]
```

**I would like it to be like this**

```
[ 

{"StateName":"Alaska","StateAbbr":"AK"}, 
{"StateName":"Alabama","StateAbbr":"AL"}, 
{"StateName":"Arkansas","StateAbbr":"AR"}, 
{"StateName":"Arizona","StateAbbr":"AZ"}, 
{"StateName":"California","StateAbbr":"CA"}, 
{"StateName":"Colorado","StateAbbr":"CO"}, 
{"StateName":"Connecticut","StateAbbr":"CT"} 

]
```

With out the numbers. How can I do this?

I tried mysql_fetch_assoc but it doesn't work it.

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $arr[] = $row; 
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: No that would not work dynamic Keys within the 2d array. Thank for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to remove the keys from the 2d array once converted to a json. Create functions to do this.

```
function remove_json_keys($array) {
  foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v)) {
        $array[$k] = $this->remove_json_keys($v);
    } //if
  } //foreach
  return $this->sort_numeric_keys($array);
}

function sort_numeric_keys($array) {
    $i=0;
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if(is_int($k)) {
            $rtn[$i] = $v;
            $i++;
        } else {
            $rtn[$k] = $v;
        } //if
    } //foreach
    return $rtn;
}
```